# Create Custom dimension based on Event in GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We already set up and event for an interaction. However, I wish this event to be captured as session level in Google Analytics. I'm wondering how I can create utilise these event variables in GTM to create a custom dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create before the custom dimension in Google Analytics, then via GTM you can send the information value in that custom dimension index with Google Analytics tag.